# Exchange 404 not found /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

Tags: exchange, log-files, autodiscovery

Yesterday I noticed that my error logs show:

" 404 Not Found
/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml: 893 Time(s) "

How should I fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to check if the autodiscover path is set correctly from Exchange.. What version of Exchange are you using ?

Comment: Not enough information. You need to include version of Exchange to begin with. Also whether it is full product or SBS. What logs are you looking at to see that error? Do you have more than one server? Does the Autodiscover virtual directory exist in IIS manager?

Comment: I really don't know what version of Exchange we use. Where can I find that? I don't have any ideas how to fix it... Is it something critical?

Answer (score 1):

First of all this error is not critical, more just for informative purposes. In order to fix this you should understand why this error occurs. Exchange does monitoring of its own. The Endpoint `/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` provides any client with the ability to fetch the needed configuration like ports and encryption. The name resolves to `domainname.tld/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` if this is not reachable by the Exchange it will throw this error. You might want to check your IIS in order if the Exchange server can reach it via localhost.